# Exit Python While Loop when socket disconnects

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I have a bit of code that receives a WiFi password from a Raspberry Pi. The Pi dishes out a new code every 2 minutes. The script below checks the password and updates the connection with the new password if needed.

```
        # Create a TCP/IP socket

s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)


# Bind the socket to the port
s.bind (('',4446))
s.settimeout(10.0)
print ("Listening . . . .")

data=s.recv(1024).decode()
print ("Password:  "+data)
os.system('netsh wlan set profileparameter name=PI_AP Keymaterial='+data)
var1=data

try:
    while 1:
        data=s.recv(1024).decode()
        print ("Password:  "+data)

        if var1!=data:
            os.system('netsh wlan set profileparameter name=PI_AP Keymaterial='+data)
            print ("Password:  "+data)
            var1=data

except socket.timeout:
    print ("Timed Out")
```

Here is the output, with the error message I am seeing after I disconnect:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Listening . . . .
Password:  m9FyvpJCILQrZB4sq125AfUn9nfS9Z6qDlbBxy12pL48y5kJTLrH01osp4xXWN3
Password:  m9FyvpJCILQrZB4sq125AfUn9nfS9Z6qDlbBxy12pL48y5kJTLrH01osp4xXWN3
Password:  m9FyvpJCILQrZB4sq125AfUn9nfS9Z6qDlbBxy12pL48y5kJTLrH01osp4xXWN3
```

> ```
> **Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\cave\Desktop\system_V1\UAD-V1.0.py", line 21, in <module>
>     data=s.recv(1024).decode()
> socket.timeout: timed out
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\cave\Desktop\system_V1\UAD-V1.0.py", line 29, in <module>
>     except socket.timeout:
> TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
> >>>**
> ```

Comment: can't you have `while data:` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should receive a socket disconnection exception, or empty data (as you tested in the if) in case of a disconnection.

If you do not receive the exception (which is kinda awkward) you may use the [`select`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html) (low-level) or the [`selectors`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html) (high-level) modules in order to see if you receive data on the line.

You may set a 2 minute timeout which afterwards the `select()` function will throw an exception.

**UPDATE:**

In order to catch the timeout exception, wrap your code like this:

```
try:
    while 1:
        ...
except socket.timeout:
    print("timed out")
...
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Seems like you're trying to catch `socket.socket.timeout` while you need to catch `socket.timeout`. I believe you used this line on top: `from socket import *`. If so, try catching `timeout` and not `socket.timeout`. That's the reason `from ... import *` is not recommended.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.

I do get the exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cave\Desktop\system_V1\UAD-V1.0.py", line 23, in <module>
    s.recv(1024).decode()
socket.timeout: timed out.

but I am unsure of how to handle this in a way so that I exit the loop.

Comment: to test I used 'print ("Success") after the While looop. I saw the disconnect exception but NOT the 'Success' message.

Comment: @Jimdog Updated answer.

Comment: Different error this time, but I can see it try and handle the exception in some way...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cave\Desktop\system_V1\UAD-V1.0.py", line 21, in <module>
    data=s.recv(1024).decode()
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cave\Desktop\system_V1\UAD-V1.0.py", line 29, in <module>
    except socket.timeout:
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what happened there, could you edit your question with the updated script and exception? (Hard to see in the comments)

Comment: @Jimdog Updated my answer.